# Programmatically change tagMode of kendomultiselect

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, tags, multi-select, kendo-multiselect

I am using kendo multiselect and am using tagMode:single.
But now i require tagMode to be changed to multiple when more than 2 items are selected.

Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

```
$(".multiValue").kendoMultiSelect({
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            filter: "contains",
            suggest: true,
            autoClose: false,
            placeholder: "Select",
            tagMode: "single",
            select: function(e){
                var values = this.value();
                if(values.length > 2){
                    this.setOptions({
                        tagMode: "single"
                    });
                }else{
                    this.setOptions({
                        tagMode: "multiple"
                    });
                }
}
```